# HTMX - Reveal doesn't work with absolute position and a fixed bottom

Tags: htmx

I am trying to get hx-trigger="reveal" to work for infinite scrolling but it doesn't seem to trigger with the div is styled with

```
position:absolute;
bottom: 20px;
```

Changing either of those makes it work.

Comment: This should work, but I believe only when scrolling the element into the viewport, not within other scrolling elements. Also, the trigger is called "revealed". Can you provide more code or a fiddle that reproduces the problem?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kxj2tqyf/ works

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/glistener/zaLhg6wk/
Here is example of not fetching

Comment: @Gunslinger you forgot to import htmx